# Acer aoa150 Problem with eth0...!

Tags: acer

As i said i have an acer aoa150.

When i wrote ifconfig in terminal:

```
root@bt:~# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:23:8b:48:88:b4  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:44 Base address:0x2000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:53 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:53 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:12753 (12.7 KB)  TX bytes:12753 (12.7 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:24:2b:13:c7:94  
          inet addr:192.168.1.81  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::224:2bff:fe13:c794/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2428 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1068 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1206358 (1.2 MB)  TX bytes:143325 (143.3 KB)
```

So there is no `eth0`. Besides rx bytes : 0 and tx :0.However I'm in Internet.
Tell me please what to do about them ?
I have wifi card Atheros AR5BXB63.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check the results of `lspci -nnk | grep -i net` . Is there any Ethernet controller listed ?

Comment: 02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 02)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Atheros Communications Inc. AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:001c] (rev 01)

Comment: So ,there you are. You have an Ethernet controller, and you discovered just now :-)

Comment: What this is mean ? Sorry for my stupid question.

Comment: hmmm, maybe I didn't understand your question at all. That's a possible scenario. What is the actual problem ? The names ? or that it seems like you have two Ethernet controllers ?

Answer (score 1):

eth0 means wired connection, but you are using wifi ....

So nothing should be done.